# Sub-Report with 2 detail Section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a main report with subreports.one of the subreport has a detail section based on dataset table, it works fine. When I tried to add another detail section binding another table from the same dataset the entire subreport shows nothing. I need the 2nd detail section to look like continuation of 1st detail section.To display both sections within a box. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible bro..... if you want second detail section to follow first detail section then you need to add 2 sub reports in 2 detail section one for one dataset and another for second dataset.

Comment: That how I have it now, it's all working but The issue is the box. i can't have the 1st detail section box extended to the second detial section which is in another subreport.I'll try find a solution by removing the box from the detail sections in the subreport and add it to 2 subreports in detail section on Main Report.